# Does the shared buffer space in PostgreSQL cache index queries?

Tags: postgresql, caching

If I want to load test against a PostgreSQL table on an index. Will the shared buffer space or any other memory component that PostgreSQL use cache the data/query plan?

I found this resource but it didn't really answer my question:
https://www.postgresql.fastware.com/blog/back-to-basics-with-postgresql-memory-components

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no shared memory area in PostgreSQL where plans are cached.

Normally, execution plans are not cached at all, they have to be generated again whenever a query is run.

There are two exceptions where execution plans are cached *in a database session* (but *not* across sessions):

- The plans of prepared statements are cached.
- The plans of SQL statements run from a PL/pgSQL funtions are cached (except for dynamic SQL executed with `EXECUTE`).